# control method of worksheet is not available

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, windows-controls

I've encountered an odd problem  in proggramming add-in for excel;
i wanna add  controls in  excel, i used this code inspiring https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442817.aspx

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var worksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
    {
        const string buttonName = "MyButton";

        if (((RibbonCheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Range;
            if (selection != null)
            {
                var button =
                    new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
                worksheet.Controls.AddControl(button, selection, buttonName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            worksheet.Controls.Remove(buttonName);
        }
    }
}
```

but controls method of worksheet is not available and i can't access it, i added Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities.dll assembly and following statements

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
```

by the way I'm using office 2007 and vs 2013 so i changed office version to 12 in DebugInfoExeName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [GetVstoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee247873.aspx) method to get a host item that represents the worksheet in the workbook, and then adds a Button control to the currently selected cell.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(
       Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
    string buttonName = "MyButton";

    if (((RibbonCheckBox)sender).Checked)
    {
        Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection as Excel.Range;
        if (selection != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button button =
               new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
            worksheet.Controls.AddControl(button, selection, buttonName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        worksheet.Controls.Remove(buttonName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using correct namespaces solved my problem which is similar:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
```